# Is it possible to "pull -u" with TortoiseHg?

Tags: tortoise-hg

When I pull using TortoiseHg, it only does "hg pull", while I would like it to do "hg pull -u". Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (global or repository) - Workbench - After Pull Operation. Select needed, I prefer "fetch". Do you want to see screenshot?

Comment: In TortoiseHg 5.9.3, you can do this from
Settings > *Sync* > After Pull Operation. The "update" selection is equivalent to "pull --update", as per the tooltip on the bottom.